# How can I make this HTML code to React js component to generate random codes

Tags: html, reactjs, generator

```
import React, {  useEffect } from 'react';

const RandomCodeGenerator = () => {
  const [randomCode, setRandomCode] = useState('');
  const [isDownloadVisible, setDownloadVisible] = useState(false);

  // Function to generate a random code
  const generateRandomCode = () => {
    const code = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 15); // Change length as needed
    setRandomCode(code);
    setDownloadVisible(true);
  };

  // Function to generate a downloadable file
  const downloadFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(randomCode)}`;
    element.download = 'random_code.txt';
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  };

  // Use useEffect to run code on the client side
  useEffect(() => {
    generateRandomCode();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once after the initial render on the client side

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-8">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-6">Generate a random discount code</h1>
      <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-md shadow-md mb-6">{`Code: ${randomCode}`}</div>
      <button
        id="generateRandomCode"
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={generateRandomCode}
      >
        Generate Random Code
      </button>
      {isDownloadVisible && (
        <a
          id="downloadLink"
          href="#"
          className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
          onClick={downloadFile}
        >
          Download Code
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomCodeGenerator;
```

How can i make this server component into client component . It shows me this error:

```
─[C:\Users\35797\Desktop\qrwebsite\qrwebsite\components\RandomCodeGenerator.tsx:1:1]
 1 │ import React, {  useEffect } from 'react';
   ·                  ─────────
 2 │
 3 │ const RandomCodeGenerator = () => {
 3 │   const [randomCode, setRandomCode] = useState('');
   ╰────

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
  ./components\RandomCodeGenerator.tsx
  ./app\page.tsx**
```

Comment: The code shown isn’t using React at all, but jQuery instead.  Where are you trying to use React?  Have you confused these two libraries somehow?  Or are you just asking this community to do all of your work for you?

Comment: I suggest you to try converting this code into React and post a question in case you got stuck or got any error that you can't resolve.

Comment: @MuhamedFazeel yes i am trying to convert the javascript code to react js

Comment: @IzabelaNedyalkova: *”i am trying to convert the javascript code to react js”* - What attempt have you made and what problem have you encountered?  Please update the question to include this information.

Comment: @IzabelaNedyalkova What I meant was you should make your hands dirty at first. From your question what I understand was you are giving out your entire task to the community instead of trying it your own. First attempt to do that and feel free to ask about the issues you are getting, if any.

Comment: @MuhamedFazeel i have updated the react js code i am just trying to figure out how to turn it into client component

Comment: @IzabelaNedyalkova You have missed to import useState.

Comment: @MuhamedFazeel once i did it still showed me  error

Comment: @MuhamedFazeel in the terminal it was saying that the parent component should be client first and then this one

Comment: @IzabelaNedyalkova Where are you using this component? I think the component inside which you are using this component is not rendered. First you need to render it to the client.

Comment: @MuhamedFazeel how do i render it to the client '

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `useEffect` hook as you're generating the code on button click event. You need to import `useState` instead of `useEffect` now.

Your import statements turns into:

```
import { useState } from "react"
```

Your `generateRandomCode` and `downloadFile` functions works perfectly fine.

**If you want to use `useEffect` hook** you don't need to create a button to trigger `generateRandomCode`. Remove the button and now your import statement becomes:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
```

Full code example:
Without `useEffect`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const RandomCodeGenerator = () => {
  const [randomCode, setRandomCode] = useState("");
  const [isDownloadVisible, setDownloadVisible] = useState(false);

  // Function to generate a random code
  const generateRandomCode = () => {
    const code = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 15); // Change length as needed
    setRandomCode(code);
    setDownloadVisible(true);
  };

  // Function to generate a downloadable file
  const downloadFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    element.href = `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
      randomCode
    )}`;
    element.download = "random_code.txt";
    element.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-8">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-6">Generate a random discount code</h1>
      <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-md shadow-md mb-6">{`Code: ${randomCode}`}</div>
      <button
        id="generateRandomCode"
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={generateRandomCode}
      >
        Generate Random Code
      </button>
      {isDownloadVisible && (
        <a
          id="downloadLink"
          href="#"
          className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
          onClick={downloadFile}
        >
          Download Code
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomCodeGenerator;
```

With `useEffect`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const RandomCodeGenerator = () => {
  const [randomCode, setRandomCode] = useState("");
  const [isDownloadVisible, setDownloadVisible] = useState(false);

  // Function to generate a random code
  const generateRandomCode = () => {
    const code = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 15); // Change length as needed
    setRandomCode(code);
    setDownloadVisible(true);
  };

  // Function to generate a downloadable file
  const downloadFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    element.href = `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
      randomCode
    )}`;
    element.download = "random_code.txt";
    element.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  };

  // Use useEffect to run code on the client side
  useEffect(() => {
    generateRandomCode();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once after the initial render on the client side

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-8">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-6">Generate a random discount code</h1>
      <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-md shadow-md mb-6">{`Code: ${randomCode}`}</div>
      {isDownloadVisible && (
        <a
          id="downloadLink"
          href="#"
          className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
          onClick={downloadFile}
        >
          Download Code
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomCodeGenerator;
```